# Recommendations on providing integration api

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, struts2, integration

Are there any recommendations, best practices or good articles on providing integration hooks ?
Let's say I'm developing a web based ordering system. Eventually I'd like my client to be able to write some code, packaged it into a jar, dump it into the classpath, and it would change the way the software behaves.
For example, if an order comes in, the code
1. may send an email or sms
2. may write some additional data into the database
3. may change data in the database, or decide that the order should not be saved into the database (cancel the data save)

Point 3 is quite dangerous since it interferes too much with data integrity, but if we want integration to be that flexible, is it doable ?

Options so far
1. provide hooks for specific actions, e.g. if this and that occurs, call this method, client will write implementation for that method, this is too rigid though
2. mechanism similar to servlet filters, there is code before the actual action is executed and code after, not quite sure how this could be designed though

We're using Struts2 if that matters.
 
This integration must be able to detect a "state change", not just the "end state" after the core action executes.
 
For example if an order changes state from In Progress to Paid, then it will do something, but if it changes from Draft to Paid, it should not do anything.
The core action in this case would be loading the order object from the database, changing the state to Paid, and saving it again (or doing an sql update).

Answer (score 2):

Many options, including:

- Workflow tool
- AOP
- Messaging
- DB-layer hooks

The easiest (for me at the time) was a message-based approach. I did a sort-of ad-hoc thing using Struts 2 interceptors, but a cleaner approach would use Spring and/or JMS.

As long as the relevant information is contained in the message, it's pretty much completely open-ended. Having a system accessible via services/etc. means the messages can tap back in to the main app in ways you haven't anticipated.

If you want this to work without system restarts, another option would be to implement handlers in a dynamic language (e.g., Groovy). Functionality can be stored in a DB. Using a Spring factory makes this pretty fun and reduces some of the complexity of a message-based approach.

One issue with a synchronous approach, however, is if a handler deadlocks or takes a long time; it can impact that thread at the least, or the system as a whole under some circumstances.